# Difference between malloc and (int *)malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc

(Total newbie here.) From what I understand, if I code the following in C:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

What this means is that I ask the computer to reserve 4 bytes of memory for me and assign to p the value of the address of the first byte of that 4-byte-chunk of memory.

At computer.howstuffworks.com/c29.htm we instead have:

```
p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

How is this different?

Comment: The C compiler should perform an implicit cast from `void*` to `int*`, so explicit casting is largely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **is** a difference; see here for a full discussion: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

The most important point is that casting can hide an error if you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` Without the cast, this is an error. With the cast, but without the include, C will assume that `malloc()` returns an `int` which may not be the same size as a pointer. In this case the return value of the real function will get chopped (if the pointer is longer than an `int`, say, on a 64-bit machine) and lead to an invalid pointer.

Comment: Just to be clear: So the second line of code (which I quoted from HowStuffWorks) is ill-advised, whereas the first line is preferred?

Comment: @KennyLJ Yes, the first line (no cast) is preferred **for pure C only**. For C++, you *must* cast (it is an error otherwise; in C++ the cast is safe because C++ will not assume the existence of undefined functions).

Comment: Unless in some rare circumstances show me a real c program that will not use the c library.

Comment: @self It doesn't have to be a whole program, just a single compilation unit (`.c` file roughly). Modules that don't reference the C library are extremely common. Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: Note that C99 did away with implcit `int` declarations, so this isn't really a consideration anymore; however, the cast should still be left off, since it's unnecessary and just adds visual clutter.  The practice of casting the result of `malloc` is a holdover from K&R C; originally, the `*alloc` functions returned a `char *`, so a cast *was* necessary if the target was a different pointer type.  The 1989 standard introduced `void *` specifically to act as a "generic" pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns a `void *` which is okay since it is safe and automatic to convert a `void *` to another pointer type. The second case needlessly casts the result of `malloc` to an `int *` and you should not cast the result of `malloc` since it can hide error messages and is not necessary. For example if you forget to include `stdlib.h` you should see a warning similar to:

> initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

since in many compilers `malloc` will be implicitly declared to return `int`.

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns a `void*` by default.

in the second case you are casting it to a `int*`

NOTE: in C you don't have to do the cast. That is, these two statements are 100% equivalent:

```
char *x = malloc(100);
 char *y = (char *)malloc(100);
```

Conversions to and from void * are implicit in C.